# how to split array in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
var rows_selected = [];
var rowId = data[0]; // conten [24,25,26,27 etc]
var namaFile = data[4]; // content [foto1.JPG, foto2.JPG, foto3.JPG, foto4.JPG ]

//If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
rows_selected.push(rowId,namaFile);

var dataId=[];
$.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId, namaFile){
  dataId.push(rowId,namaFile);
});
```

in ajax i sent dataId to controller

```
$.ajax({
   data: {"iddata": "[{"+dataId+"}]"},
});
```

but in controller iddata receive just one array like this `24,6a5236ee48848e648553a35d64c4f64dJPG,25,a31ea31db31483506fbd95e463d4c8ffJPG,26,042fd1eee499e5bb9c93853c0299b42eJPG,27,e243845bcc0447324d449e37b271c9ebJPG,28,8f331fa2a713f5268ab71698a65185b6JPG`

some code in controller

```
$iddata=array();
    $iddata=array($_GET['iddata']);
    $a=explode(",", $iddata[0]);
    $b=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $a);
    $jumlahdata=count($b)/2;
    for($i=0;$i<$jumlahdata;$i++)
    {
        //delete on database
       $data=array('id_perjal'=>$b[$i]);
       $this->M_perjal_terpasang->Delete_Foto($data);
        //and i want deleting foto with unlink
       unlink("assets/images/uploads/"$b[$i]);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the object structure that you want the server to receive, use the same sample data so it is easier for us to see the connection.

Comment: OK, i Hope this help

Comment: Which value do you want `$a` to have exactly for the given sample data?

Comment: i wanna this iddata can split to ID and file name, but content iddata just sent one array

Comment: You'll get at least better results with `data: {"iddata": dataId.join(',') }` in your ajax call.

Comment: You are also treating it as one array (after exploding the string) in your server code... so what exactly do you want `$a` to look like (I try a third time asking what you expect *exactly* based on the sample data)

Comment: sori sori my english is bad :)
in variable `$a` that i want split between content variable `24,25,26,27 is ID` and content variable `foto1.JPG, foto2.JPG, foto3.JPG, foto4.JPG is filenames`

Comment: The length/size of `rowId` & `namaFile` will be same always?

Comment: yes always, realy `24,foto1.JPG` is one object

Comment: Then create a json array like this {'24':'6a5236ee48848e648553a35d64c4f64dJPG','25' : 'a31ea31db31483506fbd95e463d4c8ffJPG','26':'042fd1eee499e5bb9c93853c0299b42eJPG','27':'e243845bcc0447324d449e37b271c9ebJPG','28': '8f331fa2a713f5268ab71698a65185b6JPG'} & send this json to your ajax data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using a naming convention, and name arrays with *plural* words, so that you know that `namaFiles` (plural) is an array, and one element of it is called `namaFile` (singular). This will avoid some confusion.

Let's say that two checkboxes are checked, and their IDs are different, then you would somehow add two rows to *rows_selected*. Currently, you push those values one after the other so that you get an array like `[24, 'foto1.JPG', 27, 'foto4.JPG']`, but you really want to get them grouped in pairs, like this:

```
[{rowId: 24, namaFile: 'foto1.JPG'}, {rowId: 27, namaFile: 'foto4.JPG'}]
```

So you should push the values like this (supposing you have an *index*):

```
rows_selected.push( {rowId: rowIds[index], namaFile: namaFiles[index]} );
```

This you would repeat for other pairs that need to be added.

In your Ajax data, you should use a JSON string, like this:

```
var ajaxobj = {
   data: {"iddata": JSON.stringify(rows_selected) },
}
```

On the server side you would convert the JSON back to an associative array, and then access the two elements of each pair by their key name:

```
$iddata = $_GET['iddata'];
$a = json_decode($iddata, true);
foreach($a as $pair) {
   //delete in database
   $data = array('id_perjal' => $pair['rowId']);
   $this->M_perjal_terpasang->Delete_Foto($data);
   //delete foto with unlink
   unlink("assets/images/uploads/" . $pair['namaFile']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowId = [24,25,26,27];
var namaFile = ['foto1.JPG', 'foto2.JPG', 'foto3.JPG', 'foto4.JPG' ];
var rows_selected = {};
for (var i = 0; i < rowId.length; i++) {
   //or check with: if (b.length > i) { assignment }
   rows_selected[rowId[i]] = namaFile[i];
}

$.ajax({
  data: {"iddata": JSON.stringify(rows_selected)},
});
```

It will return you `{"id_21":"foto1.JPG","id_25":"foto2.JPG","id_26":"foto3.JPG","id_27":"foto4.JPG"}`
So in ajax page you will get array like `array("id_21" => "foto1.JPG","id_25" => "foto2.JPG","id_26" => "foto3.JPG","id_27" => "foto4.JPG");`